# asp.net parse json and return array, get item is not an array?

Tags: asp.net, arrays

How do I return the Label, AskPrice and LastPrice from this json retrieved via the crytopia api of which there are many records in the json response.  I need to loop through them; but to do that I need it in an array. I get error "Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."

```
 'json example   {"Success":true,"Message":null,"Data":[{"TradePairId":1261,"Label":"$$$/BTC","AskPrice":0.00000012,"BidPrice":0.00000010,"Low":0.00000010,"High":0.00000012,"Volume":68064.22361439,"LastPrice":0.00000011,"BuyVolume":13524665.12308717,"SellVolume":19130552.28589448,"Change":10.0,"Open":0.00000010,"Close":0.00000011,"BaseVolume":0.00734778,"BuyBaseVolume":0.31169133,"SellBaseVolume":2961236.99999879}],"Error":null}

        Dim url as string = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets"
        Dim theurl As New Uri(url)
        Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
            Dim json = webClient.DownloadString(theurl)
            Dim d As JArray = JArray.Parse(json)
        End Using
```

Comment: It's JObject, it's not an array, {} are not arrays. And your JSON example (I now noticed the url) does not finish with a }, which means it's invalid.

Comment: Updated json example, it's valid now, that is just an example, if you hit that url you see the whole thing. Not sure if you have an answer?  Can you provide one I can try?

Comment: Yeah I'll type it now as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strong typing it's best to create a **ViewModel**

```
Class MarketWrapper
    Property Success As String
    Property Message As String
    Property Data As IEnumerable(Of DataWrapper)
End Class

Class DataWrapper
    Property TradePairId As Int32
    Property Label As String
    Property AskPrice As Double
    Property BidPrice As Double
    Property Low As Double
    Property High As Double
    Property Volume As Double
    Property LastPrice As Double
    Property BuyVolume As Double
    Property SellVolume As Double
    Property Change As Double
    Property Open As Double
    Property Close As Double
    Property BaseVolume As Double
    Property BuyBaseVolume As Double
    Property SellBaseVolume As Double
End Class
```

Then execute as:

```
Dim url as string = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets"
Dim theurl As New Uri(url)
Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim json = webClient.DownloadString(theurl)
    Dim dataWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MarketWrapper)(json)
End Using
```